# event handler priority and ignoring other handlers on some condition

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a div with 2 mousedown event handlers attached such as

```
someDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', h1)
someDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', h2)
```

from what I understand h1 will be called first and then h2 will be called, is there a way to stop calling h2 from within h1 given a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is on modern browsers, yes: [`Event#stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation):

```
function h1(e) {
    if (someCondition) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var someDiv = document.getElementById("someDiv");
someDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', h1);
someDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', h2);

var counter = 0;
function h1(e) {
  if (counter > 0) {
    console.log("h1: Got mousedown, stopping immediate propagation");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  } else {
    console.log("h1: Got mousedown, allowing propagation");
    this.innerHTML = "Click me again";
    ++counter;
  }
}

function h2() {
  console.log("h2 called");
}
```

```html
<div id="someDiv">Click me</div>
```